# How do I apply an index to many differing variables at once?

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have several vectors of differing data types, all the same sizes. Specifically, I have Datetimes as datestamps for doubles, strings etc. I wish to quickly and easily remove all weekends so I created and index from the datetimes. How do I now apply this index to all my variables?

Currently I have (for a small subset),

```
Date=Date(idx);
Meter=Meter(idx); 
Model=Model(idx);
.
.
.
```

Is there some existing function, for example, like,

```
[Date,Meter,Model,...]=fnc(idx,Date,Meter,Model,...);
```

I'v been tempted to write my own, should be very easy, but didn't want to if there is some other simple or effective alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could to it this way:

```
t = cellfun(@(x) x(idx), {Date, Meter, Model}, 'uniformoutput', 0);
[Date, Meter, Model] = deal(t{:});
```

In recent versions of Matlab you can [omit `deal`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html), and thus the second line becomes:

```
[Date, Meter, Model] = t{:};
```

---

It would be easier if instead of separate variables you had a cell array, such that each cell contained one of your variables. In that case you would just use

```
myCell = cellfun(@(x) x(idx), myCell, 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

Comment: Works great @Luis Mendo. I am not that comfortable working with cells so I am slightly reluctant to use it. They are obviously powerful so I guess its a great reason to start.

Comment: The problem with having separate variables is that, if you have many of them, they are difficult to handle, for example when you want to apply the same operation to all of them. Of course if you have three or four variables it's not a problem.

Comment: Currently, I only have a handful so not a problem, but I am looking to then scale up. I've seen `cellfun` used but never had the nuts to use it. Before I just used matrices but now I have datetimes and doubles this seems to be the silver bullet. Thank you!

Comment: If you find `cellfun` confusing (I also did at the beginning) you can use a simple `for` loop to traverse the cell array

Comment: Yes. A bit like what I used to do instead of use `bsxfun` then. This seems to have clicked. Many thanks.

Comment: Nice, but the use of `deal` here isn't really needed, right?

Comment: @TroyHaskin You are right. It used to be in previous versions, but not anymore. Fixed! Thanks

Comment: What if I wanted to set these indexed points equal to a value? eg. cellfun(@() x(idx)=0, ...). I know this doesn't work but I think it explains. Sorry, I'm tryin to use cellfun but struggling!

Comment: @josh In that case the easiest is to do it separately for each variable: `Date(idx) = value;`; `Meter(idx) = value;` etc. If that's a problem, you probably should not be using separate variables, but a cell array or struct array

Comment: Ok, Great, thanks again. Thought it best to check as I wasn't getting far with this.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to using cell fun as pointed out by **@Luis Mendo**  is to use `structfun` - that way you keep your variable names for each array.

You need to have al your variable in a structure for this to work:

```
myStruct.Date  = Data;
myStruct.Meter = Meter;
myStruct.Model = Model;
subStruct = structfun ( @(x) x(idx), myStruct, 'UniformOutput', false )
```

Comment: Good idea to keep variable names!

Comment: The problem here is the time taken to write out `Date=Date(idx);` so this doesn't quite remedy that part of the problem. Is there some other way of assigning the variables to `mystruct`?

Comment: @josh See [`cell2struct`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html).  But you still need to explicitly write the variable names

Answer (score 1):

You can define that function as an anonymous function like this:

```
f=@(idx, varargin) subsref(cellfun(@(x) x(idx), varargin, 'uni', 0), substruct('{}', {':'}));
```

Now

```
>> A=rand(1,3)
A =
    0.9649    0.1576    0.9706
>> B={'a' 'b' 'c'}
B = 
    'a'    'b'    'c'
>> [x,y]=f(2,A,B)
x =
    0.1576
y = 
    'b'
```

Comment: Very nice. Similar to @Luis Mendo's but with variable names assigned to the outputs.